# Postgres raises a "ACTIVE SQL TRANSACTION" (Errcode: 25001)

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I use psycopg2 for accessing my postgres database in python. My function should create a new database, the code looks like this:

```
def createDB(host, username, dbname):
  adminuser = settings.DB_ADMIN_USER
  adminpass = settings.DB_ADMIN_PASS

  try:
    conn=psycopg2.connect(user=adminuser, password=adminpass, host=host)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE %s OWNER %s" % (nospecial(dbname), nospecial(username)))
    conn.commit()
  except Exception, e:
    raise e
  finally:
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

def nospecial(s):
  pattern = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+')
  return pattern.sub('', s)
```

When I call createDB my postgres server throws an error:
    CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block
with the errorcode 25001 which stands for "ACTIVE SQL TRANSACTION".

I'm pretty sure that there is no other connection running at the same time and every connection I used before calling createDB is shut down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your cursor() is actually a transaction:
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor

> Cursors created from the same
>   connection are not isolated, i.e., any
>   changes done to the database by a
>   cursor are immediately visible by the
>   other cursors. Cursors created from
>   different connections can or can not
>   be isolated, depending on the
>   connections’ isolation level. See also
>   rollback() and commit() methods.

Skip the cursor and just execute your query. Drop commit() as well, you can't commit when you don't have a transaction open.

Comment: Thanks for putting me into the right direction. The solution is described here:
http://lists.initd.org/pipermail/psycopg/2002-February/000758.html

Comment: Sorry, that was the solution if you use psycopg1, for psycopg2 instead of conn.autocommit() you do conn.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT) and it should work.